VS code keyboard shortcut swallowed by terminal
In vscode, I have set ctrl + e to open the file explorer:
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+e",
        "command": "-workbench.view.explorer",
        "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.explorer.enabled"
    }

This works fine, except when I'm in the terminal where when I type `ctrl + e` I get:
C:\mypath> ^E
It seems that `ctrl + e` is getting swallowed by the terminal. In this case the terminal (PowerShell) isn't even doing anything useful with the keyboard shortcut.
How can I get `ctrl+e` to open my file explorer from my terminal?
I have tried using both bash and PowerShell. I was expecting vs code to capture the shortcut since PowerShell isn't doing anything useful with it.

Add the command workbench.view.explorer to the setting: Terminal> Integrated: Commands to Skip Shell.  Copy that command id workbench.view.explorer and click Add Item at the bottom of that setting and paste the command there.
And fix your keybinding - get rid of the - before the command, that just disables that command.  Your keybinding should be:
{
  "key": "ctrl+e",
  "command": "workbench.view.explorer",
  "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.explorer.enabled"
}

